# Schwarz inequality for integrals. Integrand function is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, inequality, definite-integrals

Let $f:(0,1) \rightarrow (0, \infty)$ be a measurable function. I have to prove that$\displaystyle \left( \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx \right) \left( \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{f(x)}\right) \ge 1$.

It's a well known fact that this inequality holds for continuous function. I think, if $f$ is aproximating by simple functions, then thesis is also true. Can I deduce from this my inequality for $f$ - measurable?

Comment: The inequality, as you have written it, is not true ($f(x)=\exp(x)$ is a counter example). Dou you mean the opposite?

Comment: Yes, of course, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*

$$1 = \int_0^1 1 \ dx = \int_0^1 \sqrt{f(x)} \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{f(x)}} \  dx \  \leq \ \cdots $$